# Solr Increase relevance of search result based on a map of word:value

Tags: mongodb, solr, keyword, relevance

Let's say we have a structure like this per entry that goes to solr. The document is first amended and than saved. The way it is amended at the moment is that we lose the connection between the number and the score. However, we could change that into something else, if necessary.

```
"keywords" : [
            {
                    "score" : 1,
                    "content" : "great finisher"
            },
            {
                    "score" : 1,
                    "content" : "project"
            },
            {
                    "score" : 1,
                    "content" : "staying"
            },
            {
                    "score" : 1,
                    "content" : "staying motivated"
            }
    ]
```

What we want is to give a boost to a solr query result to a document using the "score" value in case the query contains the word/collocation to which the score is associated.

So each document has a different "map" of keyword with a score. And the relevancy would be computed normally how it Solr does now, but with a boost according to this map and the words present in the query.

From what I saw we can give boosts to results according to some criteria, but this criteria is very dynamic - context dependent. Not sure how to implement or where to start.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is no built-in support in Solr to do anything like this. The most ideal way would be to have each term in a multiValued field boosted separately, but this is currently not possible (the progress (although there is none) is tracked in [SOLR-2499](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2499)).

There are however ways of working around this; two are suggested in the issue tracker above. I can't say much about using payloads and a custom BoostingTermQuery, but using dynamic fields are a possibility. The drawbacks are managing your cache sizes if you have many different field names and query/sort by most of them. If you have a small index with fewer terms, it will work, but a larger (in the higher five and six digits) with many dynamic fields will eat up your memory quick (as you for each sort/query will have one lookup cache with an int/long-array in the same size as your document count.

Another suggestion would be to look at [using function queries together with a boost](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#Field_Based_Boosting). If you reference the field here instead, you might avoid the cache issue. Try it!